# jQuery plugin ( bootstrap-select ) breaks when I try and dynamically generate it

Tags: php, jquery

So, I am currently learning how to use `jQuery/php` and I am a total noob, sorry for my mistakes, but here I go... I have a database, full of products, I also have a Modal (BootStrap4) that allows you to create new Receipts, these Receipts have, `Client, Title, PRODUCTS`, well these products thought it would be a good idea to dynamically generate, so I did

PHP:

```
<?php

// <option value="4" >Salsa</option>

if ( !isset($_SESSION['permission']) ) {
    session_start();
}

if ( !isset($conn) ) {
    include '../../dbh.php';
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";

$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$data = "";

while ( $rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($results) ) {

    $data .= '<option value="' . $rowitem['id'] . '" >' . "[" . $rowitem['model'] . "] " . $rowitem['brand'] . " " . $rowitem['name'] . '</option>';
}

$data = strip_tags($data, '<option>');

echo $data;
```

> this gets inserted into :

```
<table class="table" id="dynamicField">
                            <tr id="row1">
                                <td>
                                    <select class="" id="row1data" name="product[]" required>
                                        <?php include 'ProductOptions.php';?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount[]" required></td>
                                <td><input type="button" value="Add" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"></td>
                            </tr>
```

> now, each time you press the little "New item" button, it runs this
>   jQuery code

:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
        i++
        $.ajax ( {
            url: 'includes/productMovement/Receipt/ProductOptions.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(php){
                $('#dynamicField').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><select class="form-control" data-size="5" data-live-search="true" name="sel[]"><option value="1" >' + php + '</select></td><td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount[]" required></td><td><input type="button" value="Remove" name="add" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-remove btn-danger"></td></tr>');
            }
        })
    })
```

> Note: The class is `selectpicker`, and that's how the select inputs
>   take the shape

[image: What it looks like]

It all flawlessly works, one problem... The select box is all f@#3d, it won't even display the items... I tried several plugins and concluded that it isn't the plugin's fault, it's mine for not knowing how to dynamically generate stuff. I would love any kind of help, really didn't find the answer to this anywhere, and I am kind of desperate as I have tried to figure this out for 4 hours now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the new drop down with `.selectpicker()` function via js inside your ajax `success` function.

```
$('#row'+i+' > td > select').selectpicker();
```

your `click` function will look like this

```
$('#add').on('click',function() {
        i++
        $.ajax ( {
            url: 'includes/productMovement/Receipt/ProductOptions.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(php){
                $('#dynamicField').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><select class="form-control" data-size="5" data-live-search="true" name="sel[]"><option value="1" >' + php + '</select></td><td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount[]" required></td><td><input type="button" value="Remove" name="add" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-remove btn-danger"></td></tr>');
                $('#row'+i+' > td > select').selectpicker();
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Thank you!!! You have saved my life, I have tried your example but It didn't work, so I typed this in "$('#row'+i+' > td > select').selectpicker();" and it worked, thanks again!!

Posted what worked for me more exactly for anyone having trouble :)

Comment: i could not test it you are right `$('#row'+i+' > td > select').selectpicker();` works , i updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I came back to this post as I have found a more practical solution, for anyone that is trying to do what I am doing, if you have everything dynamically generating and whatever, what you actually want to do to update the element's script is ( in this case ) :

1) All of these bootstrap-select selectors have a class "SelectPicker", so what I had to actually do is update it like so :

```
$('#add').on('click',function() {
        i++
        $.ajax ( {
            url: 'includes/productMovement/Receipt/ProductOptions.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(php){
                $('#dynamicField').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><select class="form-control" data-size="5" data-live-search="true" name="sel[]"><option value="1" >' + php + '</select></td><td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount[]" required></td><td><input type="button" value="Remove" name="add" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-remove btn-danger"></td></tr>');
                // We update ALL selectpickers, so that we don't have to
                // navigate the DOM :)
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
            }
        })
    })
```